# How to enable @Valid annotation with REST Easy and Vertx

Tags: java, validation, resteasy, vert.x, hibernate-validator

I am trying to get the `@Valid` annotation working in a project that is using RESTEasy and Vert.x.

I have an API controller setup with a method signature like `public Future<SomeResponseDto> someController(@Valid SomeRequestDto dto)` where `SomeRequestDto` looks like the following:

```java
@Value
public class SomeRequestDto {

  @NotEmpty
  String someField;
  
  @JsonCreator
  public SomeRequestDto(@JsonProperty("some_field") String someField) {
    this.someField = someField;
  }
  
}
```

My expectation is that when I call `someController` with some JSON that doesn't meet the validation criteria (namely that `someField` is `""`) an error is returned and the body of `someController` is not executed. This is not the case and the body of `someController` *is* being executed.

Interestingly, if I do manual validation in the body of `someController` I do get a `Set` containing the validation error I'd expect. Manual validation uses the following code:

```java
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

final var result = validator.validate(dto); // This holds the expected constraint validation error
```

In terms of dependencies, my project depends on the following directly (listed in the `build.gradle`):

```
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider-11:3.0.11.Final
| org.hibernate:hibernate-validation:5.0.1.Final // Pulled in via the above
```

And depends on the following transitively (via dependencies of dependencies):

```
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-vertx:4.5.3.Final
| org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:4.5.3.Final // Pulled in as a dependency of the above transient depdency
```

Note: `|` indicates a child dependency (dependency of a dependency or a dependency of a transitive dependency).

Finally, I have tried following the instructions listed [here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.5.3.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Validation) to no avail (expect adding `validation.xml` since I don't think this is required). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using resteasy-reactive instead?

Comment: @JavierToja Nope! Unfortunately sine `resteasy-vertx` is a dependency of a dependency that we must use I don't think we have a choice here.

Comment: True, my fault.

Comment: You're using a much older version of `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider-11` than resteasy-vertx. That could be the issue. FWIW the artifact ID was changed to `resteasy-validator-provider` so you'd need to change that too.

Comment: Hey @JamesR.Perkins, looks like that worked! I added version `implementation "org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider:4.5.3.Final";` as a direct dependency and `@Valid` is working as expected. As a bonus question, should the versions of the validation provider (`resteasy-validator-provider`) equal the version of `resteasy-vertx`? I'll add an answer with the working solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. They're both part of the same project and while they may work with different versions, it's best to keep the version consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JamesR.Perkins suggested, this was due to using an older version of the validation provider `resteasy-validator-provider` compared to `resteasy-vertx`. Additionally, I was using the old artifact ID.

To get this working I removed `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider-11:3.0.11.Final` from my `build.gradle` and added `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider:4.5.3.Final`. Note the artifact ID has updated from `resteasy-validator-provider-11` to `resteasy-validator-provider` and I chose version `4.5.3.Final` for the validator since it matched the version of `resteasy-vertx` I was using.

For clarity, my project now depends on the following directly (listed in the `build.gradle`):

```
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider:4.5.3.Final
| org.hibernate:hibernate-validation:6.2.0.Final // Pulled in via the above
```

And depends on the following transitively (via dependencies of dependencies):

```
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-vertx:4.5.3.Final
| org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:4.5.3.Final // Pulled in as a dependency of the above transient depdency
```

Note: `|` indicates a child dependency (dependency of a dependency or a dependency of a transitive dependency).